# Program giving strange output

Tags: java

This program is meant to output a series of integers which can be read by another program (provided by my instructor; I am certain that her code is not the issue) to draw a pattern of lines.

The intended pattern is four curves which start at each corner and rotate counter-clockwise towards the center; then stops when the length of each movement is greater than the distance between one point and the next.

Looks like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/fLeHZah.png?1]

Unfortunately, the program either stops when this distance is reached by the *first* point, and doesn't allow the other three to complete, or it stops when the fourth and final point has reached this point, but in the meantime has output a bunch of other random lines that don't make any sense.

Looks like this:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/1ncJquj.png?1]

Any insight would be appreciated at this point. Code is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Slugs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File("slug_details.txt"));
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println("Sorry, file not found.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        String filename = input.next();
        int boxSize = input.nextInt();
        int d = input.nextInt();

        Point[]slugs = new Point[4];
        slugs[0] = new Point(0, 0);
        slugs[1] = new Point(0, boxSize);
        slugs[2] = new Point(boxSize, boxSize);
        slugs[3] = new Point(boxSize, 0);

        PrintStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new PrintStream(new File(filename));
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, file could not be created.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        output.println(boxSize + " " + boxSize);

        moveSomeSlugs(slugs, d, output);

    }
    public static void moveSomeSlugs(Point[]slugs, double d, PrintStream output){
        /* move slugs distance d until d >
         */
        double distance = 0.0;
        double ratio = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i<(slugs.length); i++){
            distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((slugs[(i+1)%4].x-slugs[i].x), 2))+(Math.pow((slugs[(i+1)%4].y-slugs[i].y), 2)));
            ratio = d/distance;
        }
        while (d <= distance){
            for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
                double xmoveDist = (slugs[(i+1)%4].x-slugs[i].x)*ratio;
                double ymoveDist = (slugs[(i+1)%4].y-slugs[i].y)*ratio;
                output.print (Math.abs(slugs[i].x) + " " + Math.abs(slugs[i].y) + " ");
                slugs[i].x += xmoveDist;
                slugs[i].y += ymoveDist;
                output.println (Math.abs(slugs[i].x) + " " + Math.abs(slugs[i].y));
                distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((slugs[(i+1)%4].x-slugs[i].x), 2))+(Math.pow((slugs[(i+1)%4].y-slugs[i].y), 2)));
                ratio = d/distance;
                if (d > distance && i == slugs.length-1){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the wanted output and the current output?

Comment: Done. I can't add images (reputation too low?) so I linked them.

Comment: what is an example of input?  It looks like your slugs may just not be stopping when they reach the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are suffering from severe rounding/truncation errors in your calculations, due (largely) to the fact that you are using `int` to represent the definitive X-Y locations of the "slugs".  (That is the `x` and `y` values of the `Point` objects.)

This means that you are converting from `int` to `double` and back to `int` repeatedly. Each conversion from `double` to `int` introduces an error,

I suggest you recode this using `double` to represent the true X-Y locations, and just convert to `int` values when you draw the lines.

---

(There may be something else going on here as well; i.e. some other bug that is less obvious.  But doing the calculations the way I suggest will remove some "noise" AND make your code easier to understand.)